# bash - копирование файлов из директории обработки в другую

Tags: bash

Команда копирует все файлы из директории для обработки(любого уровня вложенности) в корень другой директории где надо сохранить результат. Повторение иерархии вложенности файлов должно отсутствовать!
Пример

```
A(папка) в ней папки 1, 2
1(папка) - 1.txt 2.mp3
2(папка) - 2.txt 3.mp3
Результат:
3(папка) - 1.txt 2.mp3 2.txt 3.mp3
Важно понимать, что названия файлов могут содержать в себе пробелы и самые различные расширения.
Количество папок и их под папок в директории для обработки неизвестно.
```

Comment: это ты пытаешься переложить свою домашку на других?

Comment: да, гуглил уже очень длительное время, перебирал самые различные способы, но все равно возникают проблемы если в различных папках имеются файлы с одинаковым именем.

Comment: 1. ну так для начала надо выяснить, что должно происходить, если встречаются файлы с одинаковым именем. В одной папке не может быть двух файлов с одинаковым именем. 2. Нужно в вопрос вставить код своих попыток и написать, что именно не получается.

Comment: гуглить на английском еще не проходили? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52814/flattening-a-nested-directory

Comment: там имеется некая определенность в количестве папок и файлов, в моем же случае, количество вложенных директорий может быть бесконечно много. find . -type f в цикле for помогает, но при cp возникает проблема с обработкой имен с пробелами, которую не удаётся пофиксить. Так как цикл for не цепляет полное название файла с пробелами.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `while read` чтение идет построчное. Но цикл тут по сути и не нужен `find ... -exec cp {} /youdir/ \;` должен сработать

Comment: @Alexey, естественно ни `for` ни `while` не являются правильными иструментами для итерации через список файлов, только `xargs` (либо встроенные вещи в `find`, если файлы есть на носителе).